# iconv() - UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 fails with german Umlauts

Tags: php, iconv

I want to convert a string from **utf-8** to **iso-8859-1** in php. (actually I want to remove all characters that are not in the ISO-8859-1 character set).

```
$text = "test ‍♂️ test xäöüx x@x x€x";

$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', $text);
```

the expected output would be: **test test xäöüx x@x xx**

but I get: **test test x���x x@x xx**

why does iconv have problems with german umlauts? and why are they not removed when in doubt but turned into question marks?

Comment: What happens if you convert back to UTF-8?

Comment: iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $text): **"test  test xäöüx x@x xx**

Comment: I mean yeah... that's the right output. but I don't understand why? iso-8859-1 should contain the umlauts

Comment: It does. You have to tell the browser that the data is in `ISO-8859-1` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters äöü (U+00E4, U+00F6 and U+00FC for what it's worth) have this encoding in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout):

- ä: E4
- ö: F6
- ü: FC

If we run a variation of your code with some additional debugging information:

```
$text = 'äöü';
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', $text);
echo bin2hex($text);
```

... we get the expected output:

```
e4f6fc
```

You can see � for a few reasons, all of them related to whatever rendering tool you are using (a web browser, I presume):

- ISO-8859-1 not expected or supported.
- Missing or incorrect encoding information.
- Missing glyph in selected font (this is rare in browsers, since they use fallback fonts).